# In Jmeter, How can we use JSR223 Preprocessor to parse a CSV and filter on a particular column value to pass it as a variable to a sampler

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to JMeter and trying my best learn various things in JMeter especially regarding the CSV data processing as the application which I am working needs loads of parameterized data and I just can't create 100's of CSV filed as per the requirement and instead use a single CSV and filter the values based on specific conditions.

However, I'm finding it very difficult to write the code for this particular operatoin.

Name|Identity|Date
"001, A"|"3409ADD9"|05-01-2020
"002, B"|"BA47D76A"|05-01-2020
"003, C"|"2BC92A2D"|05-02-2020
"004, D"|"AB9AEEBE"|05-23-2020
"005, E"|"09FF417D"|05-29-2020

Note: Here I'm using | to parse as my data will contain as part of the Name as shown.

As you can see, The data is grouped by Date value. I want to use this CSV file to pass the Identity and Name value based on currentDate.

For Ex, Current Date is May-01-2020, I want to pass only those records whose date is May-01-2020 and pass it as a variable to my samplers in a loop. Once we reach the end of the file (I mean values which don't have date May-01-2020 associated with, I want to start the loop again ) and repeat from first till the time I mention in the RunTime Controller.

I went through different questions and trying to find a solution as I couldn't write one for myself in Groovy, Hence asking for help.

As per many suggestions in different questions regarding the use of JSR223 preprocessor with Groovy instead of a bean shell, I would like to seek some guidance to solve this problem to move further.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()

   def original = new File('/path/to/original.csv').readLines()

   def current = original.findAll() { line -> line.contains(new Date().format('MM-dd-yyyy')) }

   def newFile = new File('/path/to/new.csv')

   newFile.withWriter { out ->
       out.println(original.get(0))
       current.each { line ->
           out.println(line)
       }
   }
   ```

   the above code will filter the original CSV file and write only those lines which contain the current date to the new CSV file
4. Configure [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in the main Thread Group to use the "new.csv" file from step 3